# Getting segmentation fault in recursive insertion sort

Tags: c++, sorting, recursion, stdvector, function-definition

I was trying to write recursive code of insertion sort, but I am getting segmentation fault. Please help me with this.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void insert(vector<int> &v,int temp){
    if(v.size()==0||v[v.size()-1]<=temp){
        v.push_back(temp);
        return;
    }
    int val = v[v.size()-1];
    v.pop_back();
    insert(v, temp);
    v.push_back(val);
    return;
}

void sort(vector<int> &v){
    if(v.size()==1) return;
    int temp = v[v.size()-1];
    v.pop_back();
    sort(v);
    insert(v,temp);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    vector<int> v;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>v[i];
    sort(v);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cout<<v[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Navdeep Mandal This for loop     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>v[i]; invokes undefined behavior. At least before the loop you need to write v.resize( n );

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thanks a lot Vlad, it worked now. and i also got the concept.

Comment: And it would be more correct to change this condition  if(v.size()==1) return; in the function sort to  if(v.size() < 2 ) return; because the user can pass an empty vector to the function.

Answer (score 1):

This creates an empty `vector<int>`:

```cpp
vector<int> v;
```

Accessing any elements in it will make your program have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).
You can instead create the `vector<int>` with the number of elements you want by supplying `n` to the constructor, or by calling `resize(n)` after creating an empty `vector<int>`. Another option is to create it empty, and then to [`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) or [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) elements into it in which case it'll grow dynamically.

Example creating it with the correct number of elements:

```cpp
int main() {
    int n;

    // verify that extraction of `n` succeeded and that `n > 0`:
    if(!(std::cin >> n && n > 0)) {
        std::cerr << "error\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // create the vector with the correct number of elements
    std::vector<int> v(static_cast<size_t>(n));

    // use a range-based for loop to get a reference to each element:
    for(int& val : v)
        std::cin >> val;    // extract into the referenced `int`

    sort(v);

    // here you can use a range-based for loop to get a copy of each element
    // (which is cheap in this case, since they are `int`s):
    for(int val : v)
       std::cout << val << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KM6ej7jnK)

Notes:

- `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` - Never include this non-standard header. Include the standard headers, like `iostream` and `vector`
- `using namespace std;` - Don't do this. Especially not when you provide overloads for functions like `sort` that will be available if you include `bits/stdc++.h` and do `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that the vector `v` is **empty**(meaning it has size `0`) and you're trying to access its elements which leads to **undefined behavior**.

```
vector<int> v; //this creates an empty vector named v
cin>>n;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
cin>>v[i]; //this leads to undefined behavior
```

In the above snippet, the vector `v` is an empty vector meaning it has no elements. So the expression `cin >> v[i]`, leads to undefined behavior because you're accessing elements at `i`th index of the vector but there are no elements inside the vector to access.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just crash(which is what happens in your case).

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

##### Solution

To **solve** this you can specify the size of the vector when creating it as shown below:

```
int n;
cin>>n;
vector<int> v(n);//create vector of size n
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You declared an empty vector

```
int n;
vector<int> v;
```

So using the subscript operator in this for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
cin>>v[i];
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Instead you could either initially declare the vector with `n` elements after the value of `n` was entered as for example

```
int n;
cin>>n;
vector<int> v( n );
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
cin>>v[i];
```

Or you could resize the vector after the value of `n` becomes known like

```
int n;
vector<int> v;
cin>>n;
v.resize( n );
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
cin>>v[i];
```

At it would be better to declare the variable n as having an unsigned integer type as for example

```
size_t n;
```

Instead of the for loop you can use the range based for loop

```
size_t n = 0;
cin>>n;

std::vector<int> v( n );

for ( auto &item : v ) std;:cin >> item;
```

Within the function `sort` you need to change the condition in the if statement at least the following way

```
void sort( std::vector<int> &v ){
    if ( v.size() < 2 ) return;
    //...
```

because in general the user can pass an empty vector.

Instead of using expressions like this `v[v.size()-1]` you could use the member function `back`. For example

```
int temp = v.back();
```

that makes the code more readable.

I would define the functions the following way without redundant return statements

```
void insert( std::vector<int> &v, int value )
{
    if (v.empty() || not( value < v.back() ) )
    {
        v.push_back( value );
    }
    else
    {
        int tmp = v.back();
        v.pop_back();
        insert( v, value );
        v.push_back( tmp );
    }
}

void sort( std::vector<int> &v )
{
    if (not ( v.size() < 2 ))
    {
        int last = v.back();
        v.pop_back();
        sort( v );
        insert( v, last );
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void insert( std::vector<int> &v, int value )
{
    if (v.empty() || not( value < v.back() ) )
    {
        v.push_back( value );
    }
    else
    {
        int tmp = v.back();
        v.pop_back();
        insert( v, value );
        v.push_back( tmp );
    }
}

void sort( std::vector<int> &v )
{
    if (not ( v.size() < 2 ))
    {
        int last = v.back();
        v.pop_back();
        sort( v );
        insert( v, last );
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
    sort( v );

    for (const auto &item : v)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

And advice: try to avoid the using directive

```
using namespace std;
```

it can be a reason of name collisions and sometimes makes the code unclear that is whether there is used a standard C++ function or a user defined function.